# Search.asmx Changing count returns different results

Tags: 2010, search, search-results, enterprise-search

We are using SP2010 Enterprise search (not FAST) to perform some searches for articles across a large intranet site collection using the search.asmx service. We have discovered several issues where users experience having different results returned. Some are missing where others are duplicated. After trying out different combinations of parameters we have narrowed the problem down to the `<Count>` property. Only changing it and not anything else in the payload of the query gives different results.

Here is what we experience (results are ids of different articles for this example):

```
Count : 10
Result : 1, 4, 20, 193, 53, 21, 79, 32, 185, 123

Count : 11
Result : 1, 87, 185, 293, 4, 20, 193, 53, 21, 79, 32
```

Articles 87, 185, 239 suddenly appear within the first 5 results simply by changing `Count`. Why does this happen? Is there some sort of refinement going on based on that property?

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that loading more results changes the ranking somehow because more results with different properties are loaded. This behavior should change when you migrate to SP2013...